# calling String method from different class to main class

Tags: java, class

I have 3 classes; Date class, profile class and main class. I want to call a getDateString method from Date class and bypass profile class and read a scanner input file as date of birth (format example: 3 October 2019) in main class. How can I do that? Below is my code;

```
class Date
{
    //Declare instant variables
    private int day;
    private String month;
    private int year;
    
    //constructor
    public Date (int day, String month, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }
    
    // get-set methods here
    public String getDateString()
    {
        String dob = String.valueOf(day) + month + String.valueOf(year);
        return dob;
    }

}
```

[This is my profile class]

```
class Profile {   private Date dob;
   private string name;

   //constructor
   public HealthProfile (Date dob, String name) 
                            
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.dob = dob;
   }
   
   // get-set methods here
   
    public void printProfile()
    {
        System.out.printf ("Name: %s%n", name );
        System.out.printf ("Date of birth: %s%n", dob);
    }           
          }
```

[This is my main class. How can I read txt file input name and dob (3 October 2019) using the getDateString method from Date class.]

```
class Healthprofile { public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (new File ("info.txt"));
    // Declare variables
    String name;
    Date dob;
    
    Date dob1 = new Date (day, month, year);
    name = input.nextLine ();
    dob = //How can I call it here
    
    Profile h1 = new Profile (name, dob);
    h1.printProfile();
    
}
```

}

[This is data in my txt file. Other data are all working but I am having trouble reading for 8 October 2000 line because I want to read it as all 3 data types as one]

`Jonathan`
`8 OCtober 2000`

Comment: `public HealthProfile()` cannot be the constructor of `class Profile`

Comment: Java already has a Date class, but you should be using `LocalDate` instead

Comment: "I want to call a getDateString method from Date class and bypass profile class and read a scanner input file"  Create a Constructor for your `Date` Class that recieves the Scanner instance to read from.  Read from the file and populate your day, month, year fields.  Or read the values from the file first, then pass those to your existing constructor of Date?

Comment: @idle_Mind I have created constructor for Date class and created object for it `Date dob1 = new Date (day, month, year);` But I am not sure how to write for Scanner instance to read from. I tried `dob = dob1.getDateString();` and I am getting mixmatch error "String cannot be converted to Date". Any advise for that? Sorry I am beginner for Java.

Comment: You'd have to show us how the data is laid out in the file...

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my txt file screenshot.

Comment: Please delete the image of the text file and replace it with plain text (formatted as "code"). Also, have you considered formatting the text data as json and just deserializing it into your classes using one of the standard libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see there are few errors in your code:

1. Profile class includes only Profile constructor, not HealthProfile.

   ```
    public class Test3{
    public static void main(String[] args){
     Map<String,MyDate> map=new HashMap<>();
    try( Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("info.txt"))){
    int count=0;String name="";

    while(input.hasNextLine()) {
               String dateF = "";
               if (count == 0) {
                   name = input.nextLine();
                   count++;
               }
               if (count == 1) {
                   dateF = input.nextLine();
               }
               count = 0;
    LocalDate random = getDate(dateF);
    int dat = random.getDayOfMonth();
    String month = String.valueOf(random.getMonth().ordinal());
    int year = random.getYear();
    // Set MyDate class object for DOB
    MyDate myD = new MyDate(dat, month, year);
    //map.put(name, myD);
    // Call profile methods
    Profile h1 = new Profile(myD, name);
    h1.printProfile();
    }
     }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   ```

// This method will return the formatted LocalDate instance for String Date fetched from File

```
    private static LocalDate getDate(String dateF){
        LocalDate random=null;
    DateTimeFormatter df =new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy")).appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(("d MMMM yyyy"))).toFormatter();
    //DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMMM yyyy");
    return LocalDate.parse(dateF, df);
    }
    }
```

2. MyDate class will display the date value:

   ```
    class MyDate{ //Declare instant variables
     private int day;
    private String month;
    private int year;
        //constructor
        public MyDate (int day, String month, int year){
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
        }
   // get-set methods here
    public String getDateString()
    {
    String dob = String.valueOf(day) +"/"+ month +"/"+ String.valueOf(year);
    return dob;
    }
    }
   ```
3. 

```
class Profile {
    private MyDate dob;
    private String name;
        //constructor
    public Profile (MyDate dob, String name)
        {
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
     }
    // get-set methods here
    public void printProfile() {
    System.out.printf("Name: %s%n", name);
    System.out.printf("Date of birth: %s%n", dob.getDateString());
    }
    }
```